# FBNativeAdsManager nextNativeAd() is crashing if first cell

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-audience-network

Code is crashing in the following line if the cell is first

```
let nativeAdd = nativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd() as FBNativeAd?
```

I guess the ads are not ready yet or something. But is should not crash!!! I try putting it in do-try-catch but it didn't help.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        if (self.shouldShowAd(indexPath))
        {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(AdCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AdCell

            let nativeAdd = nativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd() as FBNativeAd?

            if (nativeAdd != nil)
            {
                cell.setDetails(nativeAdd!)
                return cell
            }
            else
            {
                return self.createRegularCell(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return self.createRegularCell(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post any error messages / codes that you get?

Comment: What does the log indicate where the crash happens?

Comment: Did you get it fixed? @Luda

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and seldom crash when click the ad (which is in 5th cell in [my app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/black-friday-2017-ads-app-blackfriday-fm/id397533889?mt=8), using FBAudienceNetwork iOS SDK 4.26.0 with CocoaPods)

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[FullScreenCatalogViewController nativeAdDidClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x161ff12d0

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x185dabd38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1852c0528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x185db91f8 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  UIKit                          0x18f573cc4 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185db13f0 ___forwarding___
5  CoreFoundation                 0x185c970dc _CF_forwarding_prep_0
6  Black Friday                   0x100f446e0 __33-[FBMediaView loadMultiProductAd]_block_invoke_2 (FBMediaView.m:447)
7  Black Friday                   0x100f5f9f0 -[FBAdCommandProcessor callCompletionHandlerForCommand:withAdAction:] (FBAdCommandProcessor.m:296)
8  Black Friday                   0x100f5f938 -[FBAdCommandProcessor launchURLOutOfApp:withAdAction:] (FBAdCommandProcessor.m:283)
9  Black Friday                   0x100f5ec84 -[FBAdCommandProcessor launchAppForEngagement:] (FBAdCommandProcessor.m:164)
10 Black Friday                   0x100f5ea2c -[FBAdCommandProcessor processCommand:withExtraData:adDataModel:completionHandler:] (FBAdCommandProcessor.m:142)
11 Black Friday                   0x100f444d0 __33-[FBMediaView loadMultiProductAd]_block_invoke.218 (FBMediaView.m:439)
12 Black Friday                   0x100f84540 -[FBAdMultiProductView multiProductCellClicked:withPosition:inRect:] (FBAdMultiProductView.m:115)
13 Black Friday                   0x100f83b28 -[FBAdMultiProductCell dispatchClickedWithPosition:inRect:] (FBAdMultiProductCell.m:151)
14 Black Friday                   0x100f839f0 -[FBAdMultiProductCell gestureRecognizerTappedCell:] (FBAdMultiProductCell.m:129)
15 UIKit                          0x18f848f78 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:]
16 UIKit                          0x18f84d4dc _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
17 UIKit                          0x18f337dc8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
18 UIKit                          0x18f1ec748 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
19 UIKit                          0x18f8373fc _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
20 UIKit                          0x18f836f88 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:]
21 UIKit                          0x18f8360e4 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:]
22 UIKit                          0x18f1eaa54 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
23 UIKit                          0x18f1bc078 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
24 UIKit                          0x18fafbf98 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
25 UIKit                          0x18fafe408 __handleEventQueueInternal
26 UIKit                          0x18faf7574 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain
27 CoreFoundation                 0x185d54358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
28 CoreFoundation                 0x185d542d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
29 CoreFoundation                 0x185d53b60 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
30 CoreFoundation                 0x185d51738 __CFRunLoopRun
31 CoreFoundation                 0x185c722d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
32 GraphicsServices               0x187b03f84 GSEventRunModal
33 UIKit                          0x18f21f880 UIApplicationMain
34 Black Friday                   0x100e7649c main (main.m:15)
35 libdyld.dylib                  0x18579656c start
```

Comment: I'm using FBAudienceNetwork iOS SDK 4.26.0 and update to 4.26.1 after get a lot of crash reports, waiting to see how it goes.